# Fusion Table layer intermittently shows unstyled markers on Google map

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I have a Google map with a couple of Fusion Table layers (one with markers, the other one with polygons). I am styling them on the Fusion Table UI side, and then choosing the particular style with styleId on the client side.

The problem I am having is that on occasion, the markers appear as red dots instead of with the particular marker I've chosen in the styles (using icon from column). If I try again an hour later (without changing anything), the map now renders correctly.

My theory is that it likely has to do with how/when Google caches the tiles, since I noticed it this morning (Monday) on my map, after not visiting it since Friday.

1) Does this sound like a possible cause?

2) Is there any way to fix this? Some way to "Warm-up" the cache?

For the sake of completeness, I do truncate and repopulate the Fusion Table through the API once a day. This could possibly be wiping out any previously cached tiles, if my theory is correct.

Comment: I'm using the FT API, but I assume that the tables work the same whether you are using the API or creating a map layer.  Whenever an item is changed in the table, it drops from the feed for somewhere like 3 - 5 minutes.  It sounds like this may be what is happening in your case - and the map layer then reverts to the default marker display (the red dot).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a bug that we're trying to track down. In general the thing heals itself after a delay, as you've seen, but it can revert and flip back and forth. There's no workaround that we know of right now, but we are actively searching for the root cause.

Comment: Sad to hear that! Please keep me posted if you sort this out. We're weighing whether going to production with the system as is, or seeing if we need to find alternatives. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this specifically when using multiple fusiontables layers. Reverting back to 1 layer seems to bring things back to consistency. For our production product, we've had to limit the intended functionality of the app due to this constraint.

I have tried multiple "tricks" to refresh cache, reload layers, etc. With more than one layer, we never were able to make it consistent.

Glad to hear that it's being actively looked at.